# How to hide video in the post on homepage

Tags: wordpress, youtube

I add videos to my wordpress posts, by just adding old youtube embed code, for example:

```
<object width="853" height="480"><param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/IDN7t9-2ZZE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="//www.youtube.com/v/IDN7t9-2ZZE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="853" height="480" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

But I dont want to show videos in the posts on the homepage. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a template and write this code  for just excerpts and also it may hide your video

**Most Recent Jobs and Testimonials...**

```
<ul>
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); ?> 

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

<li><a>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<li><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather not mess with the template files, you could add this simple style to the bottom of style.css

`.home object {display: none !important;}`

This solution assumes the body tag of your home page has a class of "home", which is extremely likely. Also, you'll have to make this change whenever you update that theme, or if you switch to a new one, unless you use a child theme (http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).